# Dynamic Time Warping with polarity?

Tags: time-series, rating, dynamic-time-warping

I am trying to quantify the cumulative difference between two time series using dynamic time warping. For example, here I calculated and plotted the DTW distance between Speaker rating (pink line) and the Listener rating (blue line):
[image: dtw plot]

**I am struggling with how DTW can account for polarity (or positive/negative direction) when comparing the two time series**. I would like to know how much the Speaker rating was overconfident (i.e., bigger) compared to the Listener rating throughout. As you can see in the plot, the blue line is mostly above the pink one, except in the beginning-- so I would expect to see a negative overconfidence value here.

I appreciate any help or input!